# closesocket() freeze once in awhile

Tags: windows, sockets, freeze

This is how i close the socket:

```
LINGER lingerStruct;
lingerStruct.l_onoff = 1;
lingerStruct.l_linger = 0;
setsockopt(Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char*)&lingerStruct, sizeof(lingerStruct));
CancelIo((HANDLE)Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket);
shutdown(Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
closesocket(Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket); // << Hangs here
```

After about 2~10 hours of runtime and after closing over 500 sockets, it happens that that random socket doesn't wanna close and closesocket() hangs forever on a critical section(found this out using a debugger).

What am i doing wrong?

Compiler: Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (C++)
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Thanks.

Comment: If you know it is waiting on a critical section object you can use the command !locks in windbg to figure out which thread owns which critical section objects. It is most probably a dead lock.

Answer (score 1):

The CancelIo function is not synchronous, or at least, it is not documented as guaranteed to be synchronous.  If I/O on that socket is pending, you should wait until you've received the completion notifications confirming that the I/O was cancelled (or, perhaps, completed successfully before the cancel request was queued).

Once the completion notification has been received, it should be safe to close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

```
LINGER lingerStruct;
lingerStruct.l_onoff = 1;
lingerStruct.l_linger = 0;
setsockopt(Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char*)&lingerStruct, sizeof(lingerStruct));
```

Get rid of all that. It doesn't do you any good, or the peer either. Just call `closesocket()` and let TCP work in its default mode. Or are you deliberately trying to cause a loss of data and a reset at the peer? and if so, why?

```
CancelIo((HANDLE)Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket);
```

I would be tempted to get rid of that too. Closing the socket should take care of all that I would have thought, but I am no expert on async I/O. You could try it.

```
shutdown(Clients[iClientID].ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
```

Get rid of that. It is redundant before `closesocket()`.

Comment: downvote because of windows docs explicitly states: **"To assure that all data is sent and received on a connected socket before it is closed, an application should use shutdown to close connection before calling closesocket."** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-shutdown